# Excel ODBC connection to MySQL Microsoft Query - is it safe?

Tags: mysql

I've been able to make a connection from Excel using ODBC to my remote MySQL database so I can import data. My question is, is it safe? Are the default settings used including entering your login credentials as a DSN in ODBC for the connection secure?

I dont believe any sort of encryption is done so I believe my credentials are plain text and can be intercepted. I have not been able to find much information through my Google searches and my hosting provider is not too sure either if its secure or not.

Here is a picture of my settings:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zymBN.jpg

As you can see SSL is empty, I want to see the security of ODBC then I'll proceed forward correctly on setting up SSL if needed. Note: I am using a shared hosting service with CPanel.

Answer (score 0):

The (hopefully obvious) major issue, SSL notwithstanding, with using an ODBC connection to your data source is that your document now has embedded within it your database credentials.... and of course there's no way to avoid that, it has to have something with which it can authenticate to your DB.  I would very strongly recommend you double-check that the user you're using is constrained at the DB to doing read-only operations before you do anything else (and, if that's not an option, I'd strongly reconsider this entirely).

Once you've decided to accept that risk, then yes, by all means ensure SSL is being used so your credentials and data are not being sent across in the clear.